# A property to change how a submenu unrolls?

Tags: css

Is there a CSS property to change the way a sub-menu unrolls (i.e. from top left to bottom right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess  you are looking for CSS3 transition.

[CSS3 Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)